# SubtleCrypto with rsa/ecb/oaepwithsha-256andmgf1padding

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptography, rsa

After going through [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto)  i could not find way to encrypt data with RSA-OAEP with  WithMD5AndMGF1Padding . So basically i don't know what padding are they using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For MGF1 the default is usually SHA-1, you can find this in the RSA RFC's, e.g. RFC 8017 for the PKCS#1 v2.2 standard. To be precise, see [Appendix A.2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#appendix-A.2.1):

> The default hash function is SHA-1: ...

and:

> The default mask generation function is MGF1 with SHA-1: ...

Also SHA-1 is used as example configuration in the description of OAEP itself.

MD5 is so badly broken that it should not be used even as configuration option for MGF1 - even if no attack is currently known. SHA-1 is also broken, and many libraries therefore include options to use one of the SHA-2 hash functions instead (although only SHA-512 and SHA-256 make any sense out of the 5 available options as the others are reduced output versions of SHA-512 or SHA-256).